# Image distortion with sine with cubic interpolation

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, distortion

I'm trying to do an distortion with sine/cosine on the y axis with Cubic interpolation with the next code, I'm keeping the same size of the new image as the old image . And the results doesn't look good. I'm doing the interpolation only on the y axis. I did the calculation on base of this [Math](http://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic)

```
Mat cubic(Mat old, int freq){
int height = old.size().height;
int width = old.size().width;
int p0,p1,p2,p3;
int Bp0,Bp1,Bp2,Bp3;
int Gp0,Gp1,Gp2,Gp3;
int Rp0,Rp1,Rp2,Rp3;
unsigned char B,G,R;

double Ba,Bb,Bc,Bd;
double Ga,Gb,Gc,Gd;
double Ra,Rb,Rc,Rd;
double fi,fj;
Mat res(height,width,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(100));
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        fi = i;
        fj = (j - (((height/30)*(sin((M_PI*i)/(freq/2)))))) + sqrt(height) ;
        //Get the indexes of the for neighbors 
         if(fj > 20 &  fj < height){
        p1 = floor(fj);
        p2 = ceil(fj);
        p0 = p1-1;
        p3 = p2+1;
        //get the color values
        Vec3b p0Color = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi),p0));
        Vec3b p1Color = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi),p1)); 
        Vec3b p2Color = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi),p2)); 
        Vec3b p3Color = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi),p3));
        //cout <<" fj:" <<fj<< " p0: " << p0 <<" p1: "<< p1 << " p2: "<<p2 <<" p3:" <<p3;

        Bp0 = p0Color.val[0]; Bp1 = p1Color.val[0]; Bp2 = p2Color.val[0]; Bp3 = p3Color.val[0]; 
        Ba = -0.5*Bp0 + 1.5*Bp1 - 1.5*Bp2 + 0.5*Bp3;
        Bb = Bp0 - 2.5*Bp1 + 2*Bp2 -0.5*Bp3;
        Bc = -0.5*Bp0 + 0.5*Bp2;
        Bd = Bp1;

        Gp0 = p0Color.val[1]; Gp1 = p1Color.val[1]; Gp2 = p2Color.val[1]; Gp3 = p3Color.val[1]; 
        Ga = -0.5*Gp0 + 1.5*Gp1 - 1.5*Gp2 + 0.5*Gp3;
        Gb = Gp0 - 2.5*Gp1 + 2*Gp2 -0.5*Gp3;
        Gc = -0.5*Gp0 + 0.5*Gp2;
        Gd = Gp1;

        Rp0 = p0Color.val[2]; Rp1 = p1Color.val[2]; Rp2 = p2Color.val[2]; Rp3 = p3Color.val[2]; 
        Ra = -0.5*Rp0 + 1.5*Rp1 - 1.5*Rp2 + 0.5*Rp3;
        Rb = Rp0 - 2.5*Rp1 + 2*Rp2 -0.5*Rp3;
        Rc = -0.5*Rp0 + 0.5*Rp2;
        Rd = Rp1;

        B = floor(Ba*pow(fj,3) + Bb*pow(fj,2) + Bc*fj + Bd);
        G = floor(Ga*pow(fj,3) + Gb*pow(fj,2) + Gc*fj + Gd);
        R = floor(Ra*pow(fj,3) + Rb*pow(fj,2) + Rc*fj + Rd);
        if(B==0){
            cout <<"list:" << Ba <<" " << Bb <<" "<< Bc <<" " << Bd;
        }
        Vec3b finalColor(B,G,R);
        res.at<Vec3b>(j,i) = finalColor;
    }   
    }
}
namedWindow( "cubic", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "cubic", res); 
return res;
```

}
The origin photo
[image]

The bilinear interpolation
[image]

The cubic interpolation
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Integer overflow, perhaps?

Comment: Its true there is an integer overflow on the edges of segments. I d'ont know how to solve it.

Comment: Maybe change the quantization range by some factor? You could divide every pixel by 2 (or some constant) before the calculation, and afterwards multiply all of them by 2 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
Mat cubic(Mat old, int freq){
int height = old.size().height;
int width = old.size().width;
int p0,p1,p2,p3;
int Bp0,Bp1,Bp2,Bp3;
int Gp0,Gp1,Gp2,Gp3;
int Rp0,Rp1,Rp2,Rp3;
double B,G,R;

double fi,fj;
Mat res(height,width,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(100));
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        fi = i;
        fj = (j - (((height/30)*(sin((M_PI*i)/(freq/2)))))) + sqrt(height) ;
        //Get the indexes of the for neighbors 
         if(fj > 20 &  fj < height){
        p1 = floor(fj);
        p2 = ceil(fj);
        p0 = p1-1;
        p3 = p2+1;
        //get the color values
        Vec3b p0Color = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi),p0));
        Vec3b p1Color = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi),p1)); 
        Vec3b p2Color = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi),p2)); 
        Vec3b p3Color = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi),p3));
        if(i == 258 && j==59){
        }
        Bp0 = p0Color.val[0]; Bp1 = p1Color.val[0]; Bp2 = p2Color.val[0]; Bp3 = p3Color.val[0]; 
        Gp0 = p0Color.val[1]; Gp1 = p1Color.val[1]; Gp2 = p2Color.val[1]; Gp3 = p3Color.val[1]; 
        Rp0 = p0Color.val[2]; Rp1 = p1Color.val[2]; Rp2 = p2Color.val[2]; Rp3 = p3Color.val[2];

       //Normalize the fj
       fj = (fj - floor(fj));

        B= Bp1 + 0.5 * fj*(Bp2 - Bp0 + fj*(2.0*Bp0 - 5.0*Bp1 + 4.0*Bp2 - Bp3 + fj*(3.0*(Bp1 - Bp2) + Bp3 - Bp0)));
        G= Gp1 + 0.5 * fj*(Gp2 - Gp0 + fj*(2.0*Gp0 - 5.0*Gp1 + 4.0*Gp2 - Gp3 + fj*(3.0*(Gp1 - Gp2) + Gp3 - Gp0)));   
        R= Rp1 + 0.5 * fj*(Rp2 - Rp0 + fj*(2.0*Rp0 - 5.0*Rp1 + 4.0*Rp2 - Rp3 + fj*(3.0*(Rp1 - Rp2) + Rp3 - Rp0)));

        if(B > 255)
            B=255;
        if(G>255)
            G=255;
        if(R>255)
            R=255;
        if(B < 0)
            B=0;
        if(G<0)
            G=0;
        if(R<0)
            R=0;
        Vec3b finalColor(B,G,R);
        res.at<Vec3b>(j,i) = finalColor;
    }   
    }
}
namedWindow( "cubic", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "cubic", res); 
return res;
```

}

I forgot to normalize the fj before placing it in the final cubic function

The new results:

[image]